# What's difference between instance_name[:column_name] and instance_name.column_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. I found that the 2 ways below get the same result, but I can't understand the code.

`[ ]` should be the operator for array, right? Why can I use it in the following way:

code 1:

```
drummer = Drummer.find(1)
drummer[:name]
=>"Jojo Mayer"
```

code 2:

```
drummer = Drummer.find(1)
drummer.name
=> "Jojo Mayer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is an important difference.

If you need to do some sort of processing on the value by overriding the setter:

```
class Drummer
  def name= value
    self[:name] = value.capitalize
  end
end
```

Then drummer[:name] allows you to bypass the override.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. ActiveRecord:Base instance method [] just calls read_attribute which returns the same value.

The purpose of the [] method is to allow passing the attribute name with a variable, e.g.:

```
key = :name
drummer[key]
   =>"Jojo Mayer"
```